# Trouble installing RDF package

Tags: python-3.x, installation, rdf

**My problem is:**

I am having trouble for installing RDF package. I am using python 3.6.3.

```
C:\Users\suresh\Downloads>pip --no-cache-dir install RDF

Collecting RDF

Downloading rdf-0.9a6.tar.gz (48kB)

100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 749kB/s

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "C:\Users\suresh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-62ewx87w\RDF\setup.py", 
line 1, in <module>

from ez_setup import use_setuptools

File "C:\Users\suresh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-62ewx87w\RDF\ez_setup.py", 
line 97

except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:

                                      ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\suresh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-62ewx87w\RDF\
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem, so that I can install the RDF package? Please suggest me any solution if you have ever encounter this problem before.

Comment: The package RDF is broken. It contains many syntax errors and was written in Python2 syntax. I suggest looking at rdflib. (To check my claim, look at the source, it contains many errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup script of `RDF` package is erroneous. It is specified to work with Python3 but uses the `try...catch` syntax of Python2. You can either use the package with Python2 or follow up with the developer of `RDF` package to fix the install issue for Python3. The package is broken for Python3 at the moment.

Comment: @suresh-pokharel if you find the answer useful please mark the question as answered.

Comment: The setup script was written for Python 2, you can make the setup part work by downloading a newer ez_install.py from here `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py`. That won't help you though, since the package itself too is written for Python 2.